# How to format the JQuery datepicker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have succuessfully installed the JQuery date picker (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but by default it is transparent.

I found this site which gives you css files to format the picker: 
http://rtsinani.github.io/jquery-datepicker-skins/

The skin I want to use is "cangas.datepicker.css"  found here:
https://raw.github.com/rtsinani/jquery-datepicker-skins/master/css/cangas.datepicker.css

The problem I am having is that I am not good with css and I do not know how to implement the css. I am programming in .NET MVC 4.5

My View looks like this:

```
@model GRM_Reports.Models.ReportsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<link type ="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-    ui.css" />
 <link href="~/Content/themes/latoja.datepicker.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" ></script>

    <h2>Reports</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Report", FormMethod.Post))
{

    @Html.TextBox("MyDate", Model.ReportDate)

    @*<input type="text" id="MyDate" style="border:solid" />*@

    <table>
        <tr style="font-weight:bold">

            <td>
                Report Name
            </td>
            <td>
                Number Of Rows
            </td>
            <td>
                Number Of Errors
            </td>
            <td>
                Run Report
            </td>
            <td>
                Message
            </td>
        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ReportList.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ReportList[i].ReportName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.ReportList[i].ReportName)

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ReportList[i].NumberOfRows)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.ReportList[i].NumberOfRows)
                </td>
                @*<td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ReportList[i].NumberOfErrors)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.ReportList[i].NumberOfErrors)

                </td>*@
                <td>
                    @if (Model.ReportList[i].ReportName != "Risk Metrics - MS1 VAR" && Model.ReportList[i].ReportName != "Risk Metrics - MS2")
                    {
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => Model.ReportList[i].checkBox)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.ReportList[i].checkBox)
                    }
                </td>
                <td>

                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.ReportList[i].ResultMessage)

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <button type="submit"  id="Submit_Button_Click">Submit Request</button>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#MyDate').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone tell me how to link up the cangas.datepicker.css file to the datepicker?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First. Add the css file to your css folder.

Second, replace:

```
<link href="css/latoja.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link type ="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-    ui.css" />
```

with:

```
<link type ="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-    ui.css" />
<link href="css/cangas.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The reason that we import the custom CSS after the JQuery CSS is so that the rules are not overridden. (If two rules are applied to the same element, the later ones gain precedence).

Comment: I changed the code. See above but I still get transparent. Any ideas?  Do you think there is a problem with my line :<link href="~/Content/themes/latoja.datepicker.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I don't know. I'm not sure how you're structuring things. I'd say there is definitely a problem with the line above, however. A number of spaces between "/jquery-" and "ui.css"

Comment: Those spaces just happened when I pasted the code it. They don't exist in the real code.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was this this line:

```
<link type ="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes
```

used the jquery library 1.10.4 and I was using 1.9. I didn't see this.

I just had to use NuGet to install the 1.10.4 package of JQuery UI.